# Geometric Series with fractions (summation)

Tags: summation

I am having trouble trying to solve this summation (with fraction)

$$f(n) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{-5}{6^i}$$

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0\leq m\leq n$ and $r\not= 1$,

$$\sum_{k = m}^{m}ar^{k} = \frac{a(r^m - r^{n+1})}{1-r}.$$

Hence, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{-5}{6^k} = \frac{(-5)(\frac{1}{6}-(\frac{1}{6})^{n+1})}{1-\frac{1}{6}}$$
  $$ = (-6)\left(\frac{1}{6}-\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n+1}\right)$$
  $$ = (-1)\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n}\right)$$
  $$ = \frac{1}{6^{n}} - 1$$

Answer (score 1):

For $0\leq m\leq n$ and $r\neq 1$
$$
\sum_{k=m}^nr^k=\frac{r^m-r^{n+1}}{1-r}.
$$
See [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

Now note
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{-5}{6^k}=-5\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{6^k}=-5\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^k.
$$

Comment: But how do I "move" 6^i up and get rid of the fraction? Thanks!

Comment: @monsmanr See the edit.